# ROS Answers SE migration: No /opt/ros

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Debian 10.6.4.
I have done all of the steps here http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Debian up for installation and am now at the first tutorial. I get to creating the setup.sh file in the workspace, but I have no /opt/ros! When should this have been created?

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

Did something go wrong in this step? Or the source ~/ros/setup.bashrc? Any help would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32348/no-/opt/ros/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A source install like  you did with rosinstall does not necessarily install anything to /opt/ros . `/opt/ros` is where the binary packages (.debs built for Ubuntu) install to.

Based on your rosinstall line, you should be able to find the setup.bash file in `~/ros`. Note that you likely won't have the electric directory either, so the `ROS_ROOT` variable in those tutorials is not correct for your installation either.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2012-04-22**:
Okay, I see what you're saying. I have another question though - what do I do about the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable? In the tutorial, it says set it like this export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  I looked in my ~/ros/, but I have no directory of stacks. A "find | grep stacks" in ~/ros gives me quite a few files such as ./ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/stacks.py, but no stacks/ directory. I just changed mine to ~/ros_workspace:~/ros/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and did a source setup.sh, and no error messages were outputted. Then I did echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and got an enormous path when it should only be one line. Do you why this may be?

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2012-04-22**:
wait the common stack in the example tutorial is in ~/ros so I just put the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to be ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:~/ros/:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Now I can do rospack find bfl with a successful output. I'm guessing most of these directories in ~/ros are stacks then. Can anyone confirm?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-22**:
All you should need to do is ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH . The setup.bash file in ~/ros should already have put all the stacks installed with rosinstall on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.